# $rootScope not rendered in a simple AngularJs Routing Example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

I am trying to access name and age through $scope and $rootScope, but getting error even though I feel I done all correct. Can someone help me out where is the mistake?

```
<html>

<head> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script> 

</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

    <a href="#/one">One</a><a href="#/two">Two</a>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script> 
    //app declaration
    var app = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);

    //routing
    app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/one',{templateUrl:'one.html'})
        .when('/two',{templateUrl:'two.html'})
        .otherwise({templateUrl:'one.html'});
    }]);

    //config 
    app.run(['rootScope', function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.age = 25;
    }]);

    //controller
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $rootScope){
        $scope.name = "Peter";
    });
    </script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**one.html**

```
ONE => {{name}},{{age}}
```

**two.html**

```
TWO => {{name}},{{age}}
```

**Updated Error:**

[image]

Comment: run block is syntactically wrong, DI part

Comment: use not minified angular version for readable error, or go by link in error

Comment: you should not edit code in your question and move code from answer to question, because in this case all answers will be not relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies), that first parameter should be a function

```
run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
  // This is an example of a run block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
  // into run blocks
});
```

But in your code

```
app.run('rootScope',function($rootScope,$state){
```

First parameter is **string** instead function.

So, just remove it, or if you want use injectable syntax wrap in array

```
app.run(['$rootScope','$state',function($rootScope,$state){...}]}
```

But seems you have another error: use *$state* provider, but this provider not a part of `ngRoute` module, it rather part of *ui-router*. Any way, when run block executed current route can be not defined.

Working sample without excess

```js
//app declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

//routing
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/one', {
      template: '<div>one: {{name}} | {{age}}</div>'
    })
    .when('/two', {
      template: 'two: {{name}} | {{age}}'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/one'
    });
}]);

//config 
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.age = 25;
});

//controller
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = "Peter";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Comment: @Deadpool, use **not minified** angular script, and provide readable error message

Comment: @Deadpool, btw, you wrong copy second solution: forget `$` before `rootScope`

Answer (score 1):

You should inject ngRoute as a dependency to the module

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[ngRoute]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code, angular().run() is injected with $rootScope and $state.

```
app.run('rootScope',function($rootScope,$state){
    if($state.current.name == 'one'){$rootScope.age = 25;}
    if($state.current.name == 'two'){$rootScope.age = 30;}
});
```

Since $state is not part of ngRoute module, you can't inject it.

Comment: What file do I need to include then?

Comment: $state is part of ui-router. It's an alternative for ngRouter. You can use either ng-Router or ui-Router.I would suggest to use ui-router. Before starting on it, do a walkthrough. [link](https://ui-router.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Typo error,

```
 app.run(['rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.age = 25;
}]);
```

should be

```
 app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.age = 25;
}]);
```